# Structuring a large API in a Django Project

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Right now I have a large project with an equally large API (done using django rest framework). The current structure is something like this:

```
api
|-----urls.py
|-----models.py
|
----v1
    |-----views.py
    |-----serializers.py
    |-----permissions.py
    |-----tests.py
```

etc

As you can guess, the views.py file is pretty big and I want to refactor this out. Currently I have a few options in front of me, the one I'm leaning towards is to put an 'api/v1' package into each app and use the api app to tie all the urls together and hold views that don't fall into an app.

Does anyone have any experience with this and could provide guidance?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that's how we're doing it in the project I'm working on at the moment... have an `api` module under each app in your Django project